# Javascript/JQuery how to get text from multiple select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, return-value

I want to return selected text, instead of value. I know how to return value:

```
$("#myid").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
     return this.value
}).get().join(",");
```

but I dont know how to get text. I tried in map function this.text, this.val() and so on, but none of that is working. Please help..

Comment: do you mean "$(this).text()" (as a jquery function) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [multiSelect I could find](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) uses TITLE to hold the text value

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/yzY8M/)

```
$( "#myid" ).multiselect("getChecked").map(function(input){
   return input.title;
}).get().join(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

DOM Element object doesn't have `text` property, you can use `textContent` property of DOM Element object or jQuery `text` method:

```
var texts = $("#myid").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
    return this.textContent || this.innerText;
    // return $(this).text();
}).get().join(",");
```

Comment: @mplungjan DOM Element object doesn't have `text` property. `textContent` is supported by standard browsers and `innerText` is supported by IE.

Comment: @mplungjan Can you provide a demo?

Comment: Hmm, I was going to, but `multiselect("getChecked")` sounds like a jQuery UI widget rather than an actual <select> object

Comment: @mplungjan They have `value` property but not `text` property.

Answer (score 0):

There is jQuery method .html() method to get the innerHTML.

```
        $("#myid").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
           return this.html();
}).get().join(",");
```

Comment: i think you mean `return $(this).html();`